# failure deleting blobs from azure storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I am trying to delete blobs from container. The `DeleteIfExits` returns true but nothing happens. I check the container using Azure's portal and I can still see the blobs.

What is wrong with my code?

```
   private static void DeleteAllFilesWithSameName(String filePath, String filename, CloudBlobContainer container)
    {

        String filenameWidthoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);

        try
        {
            IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobs = container.ListBlobs(filenameWidthoutExtension, true);


            if (blobs.Count<IListBlobItem>() > 0)
            {
                List<string> blobNames = blobs.OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().Select(b => b.Name).ToList();

                foreach (String blobName in blobNames)
                {
                    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

                    bool isDeleted = blockBlob.DeleteIfExists();

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e.Data);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is with the logic in your code:

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);
```

Shouldn't the above line be?

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
```

Please try by changing your code to:

```
                foreach (String blobName in blobNames)
                {
                    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

                    bool isDeleted = blockBlob.DeleteIfExists();

                }
```

Comment: Sorry. I couldn't understand what to change. Can you explain more? Thanks.

Comment: When creating an instance of CloudBlockBlob, you’re using filename variable in your code. It should be blobName. This is in the loop.